# Why is a generator produced by yield faster than a generator produced by xrange?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, yield

I was investigating Python generators and decided to run a little experiment.

```
TOTAL = 100000000
def my_sequence():
    i = 0
    while i < TOTAL:
        yield i
        i += 1

def my_list():
    return range(TOTAL)

def my_xrange():
    return xrange(TOTAL)
```

Memory usage (using psutil to get process RSS memory) and time taken (using time.time()) are shown below after running each method several times and taking the average:

```
sequence_of_values = my_sequence() # Memory usage: 6782976B  Time taken: 9.53674e-07 s

sequence_of_values2 = my_xrange() # Memory usage: 6774784B  Time taken: 2.14576e-06 s

list_of_values = my_list() # Memory usage: 3266207744B  Time taken: 1.80253s
```

I noticed that producing a generator by using xrange is consistently (slightly) slower than that by using yield. Why is that so?

Comment: `xrange` is a sequence object not a generator, therefore their internals are not exactly the same. Besides, the timings you have given doesn't really show a considerable difference between xrange and the generator. In fact the difference is negligible

Comment: One thing to fix is to actually create the list when you use `xrange`. In the `my_xrange` function, you're only returning the xrange _generator_ (it's not actually a generator). But it's not yet been processed to a full list. So it may go even slower than the numbers above.

Comment: You're only timing how much time it takes to construct a generator and to construct an `xrange` object -- You aren't measuring the amount of time it takes to actually iterate over these objects ...

Comment: Additionally, according to my timings on their creation, the `xrange` object is created much faster than the custom generator.

Comment: xrange internally is a python object without iterator but it create another object which can do real iteration, so may be there is performance penality by doing that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to preface this answer by saying that timings on this scale are likely going to be hard to measure accurately (probably best to use `timeit`) and that these sorts of optimizations will almost never make any difference in your actual program's runtime ...

Ok, now the disclaimer is done ...

The first thing that you need to notice is that you're only timing the construction of the generator/xrange object -- You are **NOT** timing how long it takes to actually iterate over the values<sup>1</sup>.  There are a couple reasons why creating the generator might be faster in some cases than creating the xrange object...

1. For the generator case, you're only creating a generator -- No code in the generator actually gets run.  This amounts to roughly 1 function call.
2. For the `xrange` case, you're calling the function *and* then you have to lookup the global name `xrange`, the global `TOTAL` and then you need to call that builtin -- So there *are* more things being executed in this case.

As for memory -- In both of the lazy approaches, the memory used will be dominated by the python runtime -- Not by the size of your generator objects.  The only case where the memory use is impacted appreciably by your script is the case where you construct a list of 100million items.

Also note that I can't actually confirm your results consistently on my system... Using `timeit`, I actually get that `my_xrange` is *sometimes*<sup>2</sup> faster to construct (by ~30%).

Adding the following to the bottom of your script:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit('my_xrange()', setup='from __main__ import my_xrange')
print timeit('my_sequence()', setup='from __main__ import my_sequence')
```

And my results are (for `CPython` on OS-X El-Capitan):

```
0.227491140366
0.356791973114
```

However, `pypy` seems to favor the generator construction (I tried it with both `my_xrange` first and `my_sequence` first and got fairly consistent results though the first one to run does seem to be at a bit of a disadvantage -- Maybe due to JIT warm-up time or something):

```
0.00285911560059
0.00137305259705
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Here, I would *expect* `xrange` to have the edge -- but again, nothing is true until you `timeit` and then it's only true if the timings differences are significant and it's only true on the computer where you did the timings.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>See opening disclaimer :-P</sup>

Comment: And moreover, the "total memory" listed in the first two cases is actually  the memory used by the Python runtime .

Comment: @jsbueno -- Oh yeah, I'm ignoring that bit completely.  It's irrelevant for all cases by the `my_list` case :-)

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment above, with your generator function and with xrange, you're not actually creating the sequence, merely creating the object. @mgilson's answer covers the calls related to *creating* them.

As for actually doing something with them:

```
>>> TOTAL = 100000
>>> # your functions here
...
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("list(my_seq())", setup="from __main__ import my_seq", number=1000)
9.783777457339898
>>> timeit.timeit("list(my_xrange())", setup="from __main__ import my_xrange", number=1000)
1.2652621698083024
>>> timeit.timeit("list(my_list())", setup="from __main__ import my_list", number=1000)
2.666709824464867
>>> timeit.timeit("my_list()", setup="from __main__ import my_list", number=1000)
1.2324339537661615
```

1. You'll see that I'm creating a `list` out of each so I'm processing the sequences.
2. The generator function is nearly 10x the time for `xrange`.
3. `list(my_list)` is redundant since `my_list` already returns the list produced by `range`, so I did it one more time without the call to `list()`.
4. `range` is nearly the same as `xrange` but that's because I reduced TOTAL. The biggest difference there would be that `range` would consume more memory since it creates the entire list first and so takes *longer only in that part*. Creating a list from xrange = range, effectively. So the final memory used would be the same and since I'm merely creating a list out of the xrange, it's hard to see the difference in this trivial case.